# Как работает animation delay?

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation

Подскажите как настроить анимацию, чтобы она работала последовательно, верх-право-низ-лево. Не пойму как работает animation delay? Он как-то странно делей делает

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 .btn__line {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
 .btn__line--top {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #fff);
}
 .btn__line--bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #fff);
}
 .btn__line--right {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #fff);
}
 .btn__line--left {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, #fff);
}
 .active-btn .btn__line--top {
  animation: anim1 2s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
 .active-btn .btn__line--right {
  animation: anim4 2s infinite;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
 .active-btn .btn__line--bottom {
  animation: anim2 2s infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
 .active-btn .btn__line--left {
  animation: anim3 2s infinite;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
 @keyframes anim1 {
  from {
   left: -100%;
 }
  to {
   left: 100%;
 }
}
 @keyframes anim2 {
  from {
   right: -100%;
 }
  to {
   right: 100%;
 }
}
 @keyframes anim3 {
  from {
   bottom: -100%;
 }
  to {
   bottom: 100%;
 }
}
 @keyframes anim4 {
  from {
   top: -100%;
 }
  to {
   top: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="bnt__box">
  <a href="#" class="btn active-btn">
    <span class="btn__line btn__line--top"></span>
    <span class="btn__line btn__line--right"></span>
    <span class="btn__line btn__line--bottom"></span>
    <span class="btn__line btn__line--left"></span>
      Demo
  </a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C animation-delay все хорошо, он отсрачивает запуск анимации, но только ее первый запуск. Дальше анимация длительностью 2 секунды будет проигрываться заново сразу после завершения

Если же вам надо пустить бегущую линию по кругу, то можете попробовать сделать вот так.

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 .btn__line {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
 .btn__line--top {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #fff);
}
 .btn__line--bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #fff);
}
 .btn__line--right {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #fff);
}
 .btn__line--left {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, #fff);
}
 .active-btn .btn__line--top {
  animation: anim1 8s infinite;
}
 .active-btn .btn__line--right {
  animation: anim4 8s infinite;
}
 .active-btn .btn__line--bottom {
  animation: anim2 8s infinite;
}
 .active-btn .btn__line--left {
  animation: anim3 8s infinite;
}
 @keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
   left: -100%;
 }
  25%, 100% {
   left: 100%;
 }
}
 @keyframes anim2 {
  0%, 50% {
   right: -100%;
 }
  75%, 100% {
   right: 100%;
 }
}
 @keyframes anim3 {
  0%, 75% {
   bottom: -100%;
 }
  100% {
   bottom: 100%;
 }
}
 @keyframes anim4 {
  0%, 25% {
   top: -100%;
 }
  50%, 100% {
   top: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="bnt__box">
  <a href="#" class="btn active-btn">
    <span class="btn__line btn__line--top"></span>
    <span class="btn__line btn__line--right"></span>
    <span class="btn__line btn__line--bottom"></span>
    <span class="btn__line btn__line--left"></span>
      Demo
  </a> 
</div>
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 .btn__line {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
 .btn__line--top {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #fff);
}
 .btn__line--bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #fff);
}
 .btn__line--right {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #fff);
}
 .btn__line--left {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, #fff);
}
 .active-btn .btn__line--top {
  animation: anim1 4s infinite;
     animation-delay: 0s;
}
 .active-btn .btn__line--right {
  animation: anim4 4s infinite;
     animation-delay: 1s;
}
 .active-btn .btn__line--bottom {
  animation: anim2 4s infinite;
     animation-delay: 2s;
}
 .active-btn .btn__line--left {
  animation: anim3 4s infinite;
     animation-delay: 3s;
}
 @keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
   left: -100%;
 }
  33%, 100% {
   left: 100%;
 }
}
 @keyframes anim2 {
  0% {
   right: -100%;
 }
  33%, 100% {
   right: 100%;
 }
}
 @keyframes anim3 {
  0% {
   bottom: -100%;
 }
  33%, 100% {
   bottom: 100%;
 }
}
 @keyframes anim4 {
  0% {
   top: -100%;
 }
  33%, 100% {
   top: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="bnt__box">
  <a href="#" class="btn active-btn">
    <span class="btn__line btn__line--top"></span>
    <span class="btn__line btn__line--right"></span>
    <span class="btn__line btn__line--bottom"></span>
    <span class="btn__line btn__line--left"></span>
      Demo
  </a> 
</div>
```